# Is it possible to add values together that are associated with different row names while keeping other rows intact?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to add two values together that are associated to two different rows that have different names values. I would normally adds the values using the group function, however the group function only works for matching strings.

```
| Direction |  | Total |
------------+--+--------
|   Test1   |  | 5000  |
|   Test2   |  | 3000  |
|   Test3   |  | 2000  |
```

Expected outcome (adding Test1 + Test2) while keeping Test 3 in the table:

```
|  Direction  |  | Total |
--------------+--+--------
| Test1plus2  |  | 8000  |
|   Test3     |  | 2000  |
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a conditional expression:

```
select (case when direction in ('test1', 'test2') then 'test1plus2'
             else direction
        end) as direction_group,
       sum(total) as total
from t
group by direction_group;
```